# can't play this file error using react-native-expo

Tags: react-native

[I want to play a video but i face the can't play this video file error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFI4d.png)

When I try it with [this link](https://mirchistatus.com/files/download/id/38247), the video is properly downloaded and also played but with [this link](https://www.instagram.com/p/CET9SzMpCYg/?utm_source=ig_web_copy_link), it says the video file is corrupt.

```
const downloadFile = () => {
  const uri = "instagram.com/p/CET9SzMpCYg/?utm_source=ig_web_copy_link"
  let fileUri = FileSystem.documentDirectory +"video.mp4";
  FileSystem.downloadAsync(uri,fileUri)
    .then(({ uri }) => { saveFile(uri); })
    .catch(error => { console.error(error); })
}


const saveFile = async fileUri => {
  const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
  if (status === "granted") {
    const asset = await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(fileUri);
    await MediaLibrary.createAlbumAsync("Download", asset, false);
    alert('Saved to Downloads');
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide any related code as text, you should use images only to help further :)

Comment: const  downloadFile = () => {
    const uri = "https://www.instagram.com/p/CET9SzMpCYg/?utm_source=ig_web_copy_link"
    
    let fileUri = FileSystem.documentDirectory +"video.mp4";
     FileSystem.downloadAsync(uri,fileUri)
      .then(({ uri }) => {
        saveFile(uri);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      })
  }

Comment: const saveFile = async fileUri => {
    const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
    if (status === "granted") {
      const asset = await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(fileUri);
      await MediaLibrary.createAlbumAsync("Download", asset, false);

      alert('Saved to Downloads');
    }
  }

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NWSp.png